# Why is /fill command using the wrong item?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Currently, I'm having problems involving the `/fill` command and deadbushes.

When I try the `/fill` command with `minecraft:tallgrass`, **instead of grass, I get deadbushes**.

What am I missing?

Comment: What happens when you try? What is your complete command you try?

Comment: @APCoding Command: **/fill 10 100 1000 100 100 1100 minecraft:tallgrass**. Two notes: 1. minecraft:grass is a dirt block with grass on top. 2. These are not the exact coordinates. When I try the command, deadbushes appear instead of grass.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using the **[fill command:](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#fill)**

`fill <x1> <y1> <z1> <x2> <y2> <z2> <TileName> [dataValue] [oldBlockHandling] [dataTag]`

**`[datavalue]`** specifies the **type** of a block.

For **Grass**, the following data values each specify a type of **Grass**.

- **0** corresponds to **Shrub**
- **1** corresponds to **Tall Grass**
- **2** corresponds to **Fern**

You may be using a **dataValue** of **0** by default.

**`(minecraft:double_plant)`** also provides more options for Grass, also adjustable by the **dataValue**, like above. Those **dataValues** can be found on [the wiki page for Grass.](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Grass)